# Second date Picker should show dates after the date selected from first date picker

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two date pickers. In first I'm selecting a date, and I want second date picker to show the dates after that selected first picker date. Previous dates should be disabled.

```
     else if textFieldType == .RequestFromDate
            {
                addToolBar()
                requestFromdatePicker.datePickerMode = .date
                textField.inputView = requestFromdatePicker
                requestFromdatePicker.minimumDate = Date()
                requestFromdatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerRequestFromDateClicked(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

            }

 else if textFieldType == .RequestToDate
        {
            addToolBar()
            requestTodatePicker.datePickerMode = .date
            textField.inputView = requestTodatePicker
            requestTodatePicker.minimumDate = requestFromdatePicker.date
            requestTodatePicker.date = requestFromdatePicker.date
            requestTodatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerRequestToDateClicked(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        }
```

Comment: What you doing is correct.. but check that you properly showing two date pickers.. Because you may checking two dates in same date picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can do it like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//label for first date picker result
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

//first date picker
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

//secomnd date picker
@IBOutlet weak var secondDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

//Action - Value changed for first date picker
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    //here you are getting date as its action for value changed
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        dateLabel.text = strDate

    //here you can just update second date picker date when value of first date picker is changed
        secondDatePicker.date = datePicker.date

    //set the minimum date so past dates dont be selected
    //even if user scroll to past dates they wont be selected
    //picker wil automatically come to minimum date
    secondDatePicker.minimumDate = datePicker.date
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Link for Video - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O3avb_n-CPF_7aLat9oX-nzV7k5KklFe

Comment: I mean sample project

Comment: Actually,I cant send you project ,can u help me in this code?

Comment: Difficult to understand code in comments should I share my sample code ? you will know where you committed mistake

Comment: share me Ui where these pickers are displayed so I can try creating a sample app for you